# Issues with add and delete rows with one to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Both of the tables include unique constraints. I have been strugling with this for some time now. What should the command be for adding and deleting?

Adding by doing

```
movie = Movie(title="transformers", director="mb")
movie2 = Movie(title="transformers2", director="mb")
genre = Genre(category="action")
db.session.add(movie)
db.session.add(movie2)
movie.genres.append(genre)
movie2.genres.append(genre)
db.session.commit()
```

Gives

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('action',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Deleting by doing

```
db.session.delete(Movie.query.filter_by(title="t1").first())
db.session.commit()
```

Does not delete

Whats expected:

- Adding a new row if the title is not existing in Movie table, add a new row if the genre is not existing in Genre table and create a link in the Association table.
- Deleting the title from Movie table and removing the link from Association table. Do nothing for genre.

Do I need to change my model?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:?charset=utf8'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_ECHO = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = 'False'
    FLASK_ENV = 'test'
    DEBUG = True


db = SQLAlchemy()
conf = Config()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(conf)
    db.init_app(app)

    return app


class Rating(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ratings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("movies.id"), primary_key=True,)
    rating = db.Column(db.String(4), index=True, nullable=False,)
    movie = db.relationship("Movie", back_populates="rating",)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.rating)


Association = db.Table('association',
                       db.Column('movies_id', db.Integer,
                                 db.ForeignKey('movies.id'), index=True,),
                       db.Column(
                           'genres_id',
                           db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('genres.id'), index=True,),
                       )


class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True,)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False,)
    director = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=False,
                         unique=False, nullable=False)
    rating = db.relationship(
        "Rating", uselist=False, back_populates="movie"
    )
    genres = db.relationship(
        "Genre", secondary='association', backref=db.backref('movies'),
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
    )
    category = db.Column(
        db.String(80),
        index=True,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False,
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.category)


app = create_app()
context = app.app_context()
context.push()
db.create_all()

movie = Movie(title="transformers", director="mb")
rating = Rating(rating="5", movie=movie)
genre = Genre(category="action")
db.session.add_all([movie, rating])
movie.genres.append(genre)

try:
    db.session.commit()
    print("commit successfull")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e}")
    db.session.rollback()

movie2 = Movie(title="transformers2", director="mb")
rating = Rating(rating="5", movie=movie2)
genre2 = Genre.query.filter_by(category="action").first()
db.session.add_all([movie2, rating])
movie2.genres.append(genre2)

try:
    db.session.commit()
    print("commit successfull")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e}")
    db.session.rollback()

to_delete = Movie.query.filter_by(title="transformers").first()

try:
    db.session.delete(to_delete)
    db.session.commit()
    print("deletion successfull")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e}")
    db.session.rollback()

context.pop()
```

This results in a

```
commit successfull
commit successfull
Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'ratings.id' on instance '<Rating at 0x2022c81bdc8>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you model indeed is as simple as you write, I would use the [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to simplify such many-to-many relationship.

Your code will change in the following way:

- add a `_genre_find_or_create` function:

```
def _genre_find_or_create(category):
    obj = Genre.query.filter_by(category=category).first()
    return obj or Genre(category=category)
```

- change the `Movie` definition to *wrap* the `genres`

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    # ...

    _genres = db.relationship(
        "Genre",
        secondary="association",
        backref=db.backref("movies"),
    )
    genres = association_proxy(
        "_genres",
        "category",
        creator=_genre_find_or_create,
    )
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
# pre-adding data to ensure the category already exists
genre = Genre(category="action")
db.session.add(genre)
db.session.commit()

# adding new data
movie = Movie(title="transformers")  # , director="mb")
movie2 = Movie(title="transformers2")  # , director="mb")
db.session.add(movie)
db.session.add(movie2)
# OLD way:
# genre = Genre(category="action")
# movie.genres.append(genre)
# movie2.genres.append(genre)
# NEW way: use just 'category'
movie.genres.append("action")
movie2.genres.append("action")

db.session.commit()
```

---

*See also another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26103003/99594) with this solution.*

---

I still do not understand why you have issues with `DELETE` though. Your sample code runs correctly, producing the SQL statements below when I run it:

```
DELETE FROM association WHERE association.movies_id = ? AND association.genres_id = ?
DELETE FROM movies WHERE movies.id = ?
```

---

**Update: deletion**
Given updated model, it is clear that the deletion is related to the one-to-one relationship between `Movie` and `Rating`.

The simple solution would be to add `cascade="delete"` to the `Movie.rating` relationship, which will delete the `Rating` related instance in situations where the `Movie` is deleted:

```
rating = db.relationship(
    "Rating",
    uselist=False,
    back_populates="movie",
    cascade="delete",  # <- **NEW**
)
```

*Read more on [Cascades](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html)*

Comment: I have added an MRE now

Comment: @TheWorker, i have updated the answer taking into account the new information you provided.

Comment: Simultaneous edits :-) @TheWorker, my updated answer was inspired by van's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699651/5320906) - they are probably more deserving of the bounty than I.

Comment: Thank you, @snakecharmerb. _Knowing we are out there to support each other is the best Bounty for my Saturday._

Comment: That is a nice solution. I have added the association proxy to my model and it seems to work well, except for when I query for all movies, their ratings and all genres connected to each title. My old query does no longer work and I get the error      ´NotImplementedError: The association proxy can't be used as a plain column expression; it only works inside of a comparison expression´ .

Comment: You can still use the original relationship underlying the `association_proxy` to compose the joins between the queries (In my answer it is named `_genres`).

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 3):

The `IntegrityError` occurs because there is already an action genre in the genre table.  In this situation the existing genre must be fetched from the database

```py
movie = Movie(title="transformers", director="mb")
movie2 = Movie(title="transformers2", director="mb")
genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category="action").first()
db.session.add(movie)
db.session.add(movie2)
movie.genres.append(genre)
movie2.genres.append(genre)
db.session.commit()
```

I can't reproduce the deletion problem in the original version of the question.  However the error

```
Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'ratings.id' on instance '<Rating at 0x2022c81bdc8>'
```

Can be removed by configuring a delete [cascade](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#cascades) on the ratings relationship in the movies model.

```py
    rating = db.relationship(
        "Rating", uselist=False, back_populates="movie",
        cascade='save-update, merge, delete',
    )
```

This ensures that when a movie is deleted, the associated rating is also deleted.  Without it, as you have found, SQLAlchemy doesn't try to delete the associated rating, leading to the error.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.